# Check null for $_GET['content'] in php

Tags: php

To get data from url I used

```
$_GET['content']
```

But at initial time it hase no value for that link.

How do I check that null value

Comment: Can you give me that link

Comment: if (isset($_GET['content']) && $_GET['content']!=null ) {}